# How can I split a word from within brackets using the Split method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

How can I split a word from within brackets like:

```
(animal)
```

I need to take only the word "animal" using C# split.

Comment: Is this homework? Please tag appropriately if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need to use split()?

If it is as simple as you stated wouldn't

```
string justWord = "(animal)".Replace("(","").Replace(")","")
```

be more efficient and clearer?

Comment: I suspect you're probably right, but only for reasons of clarity. I doubt `Replace` is much more efficient than `Split`, and this really shouldn't be a motivating factor in the decision. Still, +1 for giving some thought to the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to split on brackets this will do:

```
string test = "(duck)(monkey)";
string[] animals = test.Split(new [] {'(', ')'}, 
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

animals now contains `{ "duck", "monkey"}`. For a single animal input (i.e. `(animal)`) just take `animals[0]` or evaluate directly:

```
string animal = test.Split(new [] {'(', ')'}, 
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for the `String.Split` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) already gives you examples of how to do this. Just specify the brackets as the delimiter characters you want to split on:

```
string originalString = "(animal)";
string[] newString = originalString.Split(new char[] {'(', ')'});
```

Output:

```
{"", "animal", ""}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the trim is enough to do this

```
 string originalString = "(animal)";
    originalString =  originalString.Trim('(',')');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is

```
string searchValues = "(duck)(monkey)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(searchValues, @"\w+");
var values = (from matche in matches.Cast<Match>() select matche.Value).ToList();
```